# HTML element nested in mat-grid-tile cannot be found

Tags: angular-material, openlayers, angular7

I try to show a openlayers map in a `mat-grid-tile` of a `mat-grid-list`.

Template snippet:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="100px">[...]
<mat-grid-tile
      colspan="1"
      rowspan="5">
        <div
          id="map"
          class="map">
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>[...]
</mat-grid-list>
```

The openlayers map is initialized in the typescript file. Snippet:

```
import OlTileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OlMap from 'ol/Map';
import OlOverlay from 'ol/Overlay';
import * as proj from 'ol/proj';
import OlXYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import OlView from 'ol/View';
import OlFeature from 'ol/Feature';
import OlVectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import OlStyleStyle from 'ol/style/Style';
import OlIconStyle from 'ol/style/Icon';
import OlOsmSource from 'ol/source/OSM';
import OlVectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import OlPoint from 'ol/geom/Point';

[...]
  map: OlMap;
  popup: OlOverlay;
  source: OlXYZ;
  layer: OlTileLayer;
  view: OlView;
  olOverlay: OlOverlay;
  olFeature: OlFeature;
  markerSource: OlVectorSource;
  markerStyle: OlStyleStyle;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.setMarkerSource();
    this.setMarkerStyle();
    this.setMap();
  }

 private setMap() {
    this.map = new OlMap({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new OlTileLayer({
          source: new OlOsmSource()
        }),
        new OlVectorLayer({
          source: this.markerSource,
          style: this.markerStyle
        })
      ],
      view: new OlView({
        center: proj.fromLonLat([7.35077565, 49.92363955]),
        zoom: 7
      })
    });
  }

  private setMarkerSource() {
    this.markerSource = new OlVectorSource();
  }

  private setMarkerStyle() {
    this.markerStyle = new OlStyleStyle({
      image: new OlIconStyle(
        /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
          opacity: 0.75,
          src: 'path-to-icon.png'
        })
      )
    });
  }
```

The issue is, that the target property cannot be set as the div with the id 'map' cannot be found.
I also tried with `document.getElementById('map')` but it is null.
First I had the map initialization in `ngOnInit()`, then I moved it to `ngAfterViewInit()`. Another approach was to write the div like this:

```
<div #mapDiv class="map></div>
```

and to call it in the ts file with:

```
@ViewChild('mapDiv')
  mapDiv: ElementRef;
[...]
this.map = new OlMap({
      target: this.mapDiv.nativeElement,
[...]
```

but it says that this.mapDiv is undefined.
If I set the map div outside the `mat-grid-tile`/`mat-grid-list`, it works just fine.

What can I do to place the map inside the `mat-grid-tile`?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no obvious reason why the `<div #mapDiv class="map></div>` and `ngAfterViewInit()` approach would not work. Please post a working sample on Stackblitz. Also, it is not clear what your overall design is, but it sounds like this 'map' should be a custom component, and doing that might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your comment.
In fact, after stopping and restarting the app, the above code works faultlessly.
No idea what the problem was.